# Where do I find a file I saved on android?

Tags: java, android, io

I have successfully been able to save a file to my internal storage on android using the following code in java/android:

```
public void writeToFile(String filename) {
    String code = getIntent().getStringExtra("code_full");

    String fullCode = code;

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(filename + ".cs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutputStream.write(fullCode.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved as " + filename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I do not know where I can find the saved file in my android's folders (I am trying to find it on my PC with the phone plugged in.)

Anyone know where to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you saved a file to internal storage and want a String of the path to the file, you would do `getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: I'm trying to find the path to the file in the device, how would I find it doing this method?

Comment: Just use the code above. So for example, when I run the line `String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();`, for the value of "path" I get: `/data/user/0/com.mypackage.myproject/files`.

Comment: It returned data/data/com.package.project/files but that path doesnt exist?

Comment: @ZyDevs It does exist - but only accessible from your app - run-as is your friend

Comment: I'm trying to have the file accessible to the user, is there any way I can do that? (So the user can export the file to their PC) @ligi

Comment: You cannot access the internal storage through a PC, as this directory is only for use by the app itself. You would have to write to External storage if you want the user to be able to find the file on their PC.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for how to write to external storage? that'd be very useful, thanks! @drschultz

Comment: @ZyDevs - Check out the Google guide for writing to storage. It pretty much has everything you need to know. Find it here: [http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: Thanks @drschultz, I've figured it out!

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer if you felt it helped solve your issue. Thanks!